# How to exclude additional metadata when localizing i18n strings

Tags: angular, localization, angular-i18n

When upgrading to angular 6.1.1, it looks like there are some additional metadata tags which are now being included in the xmb file that's generated. For example, this is an example of a snippet from an xmb using angular 4:

```
<msg id="1143311040585987910" desc="description" meaning="channel#id">
<source>mycomponent.ts:8,10</source>
    Hello
<ph name="INTERPOLATION">
  <ex>INTERPOLATION</ex>
</ph>?
```

and here is the output after upgrading to angular 6.1.1:

```
<msg id="1143311040585987910" desc="description" meaning="channel#id">
<source>mycomponent.html:8,10</source>
    Hello
<ph name="INTERPOLATION">
  <ex>{{ (target$ | async)?.token | async }}</ex>
</ph>?
```

Notice how the interpolated string is now getting output in the interpolation section (`<ex>{{ (target$ | async)?.token | async }}</ex>`).

Is it possible to disable this when running `npm run xi18n`? It is causing a lot of issues with our localization process and we'd rather not write a string parser that runs every time